# CentOS SSH to AWS EC2 Instance crashes/freezes

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to an AWS EC2 Instance running the Amazon AMI.

I've downloaded my security group key pair and set the correct permissions.

```
chmod 400 ~/Downloads/keyPairFile.pem
```

I then tried to connect to the ssh via the public DNS address.

```
ssh -v -i ~/Downloads/keyPairFile.pem ec2-user@ec2-ip.region.compute.amazonaws.com
```

and I get the following verbose output.

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-ip.region.compute.amazonaws.com [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ~/Downloads/keyPairFile.pem type -1
debug1: identity file ~/Downloads/keyPairFile.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-ip.region.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ~/Downloads/keyPairFile.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=none
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

and at this point the terminal hangs, everytime. 
Not even a ^C escape works.

Could anyone help?

**EDIT: UPDATE.**
I just tried to connect to the instance using the Java Client SSH that AWS offers in their console. This also seems to hang when trying to connect. I get the following output.

```
MindTerm home: ~/.mindterm/
SSH Server/Alias: [ip here]
Connected to server running SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2

Server's hostkey (ssh-dss) fingerprint:
openssh md5:  [openssh hash here]
bubblebabble: [bubblebabble here]
```

**However,** the Java client on my Windows 7 Desktop is perfectly functional.

Comment: Did you try to connect to this instance from other PC ?
Did you try to connect to this instance via Java client of the AWS using the key?

Comment: As explained above, I've tried both those methods and both hang.

Comment: I also face the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when the webapp can't find your pem file. Check your filepath and syntax to make 100% sure everything is correct. On my mac, the answer involved using using forward slashes instead of back slashes (like the example suggests). Ended up using:

/Users/david/Desktop/keypair.pem